# How to get the first four values from Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Here is `HashMap<Integer, String>` for storing value, and `String` associated with this value.   As far as I know, when you put value and `String` into the `HashMap`, which will sort by the value (because the value here is `Integer`) in ascending order.
**And Now, what I want to do is to get values from rank1 to rank4, if I do not know the value of key, how should I do that?**

Comment: use a `TreeMap` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: A hash map does not sort it's value by default to do that you'll want a TreeMap then KeySet will give you the keys in ascending order. From there you can easily get the first 4

Comment: You're mixing the terms "key" (not mentioned, but I guess its Integer here) and "value", which makes your question hard to read.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is incorrect:

> hashmap, which will sort by the value

HashMap does *not* order by keys.  If you want that, you ought to use TreeMap.  It uses the natural ordering of the keys.

If you use LinkedHashMap, it'll preserve the insertion order for you.  Maybe knowing that would be useful.

You'd do well to spend less time here asking questions that are better answered by spending more time carefully reading the javadocs for all the classes that implement the `Map` interface.  Maybe a tour through the collections tutorial would help, too.

Comment: okay, another question is: if one value with its key need to add into the TreeMap, but there exits the same key in the TreeMap, will the incoming value overwrite the exiting value?

Comment: another question, if I use TreeMap, how can I get the first four values? I only see firstkey() for return value with lowest key

Comment: @Ivy Guy, go read the api for TreeMap. All the answers are there.

Comment: Yes, if you enter a value with a key that already exists in any Map the old value is overwritten.  If you want to save both you need a multimap or a Map with a List as the value.  Dude, you need to read and think more.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is never sorted.

`TreeMap`, on the contrary is sorted on natural order with `Integer`.

Thus, you can use a `TreeMap` and iterate over it to retrieve the 4 first values.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` does not sort anything, It inserts elements into based on hascode and equals method of the elements. use `Treemap` instead if you need sorting of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TreeMap` which is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time.

`HashMap` does not maintain order.

For more info refer [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap will not sort the value you are putting in hashmap.